# Error when running a parameter query from access 2007 in excel vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, parameters, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a query in an Access 2007 database from an Excel 2007 VBA script. The Access query has parameters called "Year" and "Month".

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
Sub RunMyQuery()

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim stQRY As String
    Dim stCon As String
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim prmYear As New ADODB.Parameter
    Dim prmMonth As New ADODB.Parameter

    dbPath = "<PATH_TO_MY_DB>"

    stCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
         & "Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

    cn.Open (stCon)
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

    Set prmYear = cmd.CreateParameter("Year", adNumeric, adParamInput, , 2011)
    Set prmMonth = cmd.CreateParameter("Month", adNumeric, adParamInput, , 5)

    cmd.Parameters.Append prmYear
    cmd.Parameters.Append prmMonth

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Month_Totals]"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdTable

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I run this, the code stops on "cmd.Execute" with

> Run-time error '-214217900 (80040e14)':
>
> Syntax error in FROM clause.

What am I getting wrong?

- The command text seems simple enough to me. Am I missing something there?
- Am I misusing the parameters functionality of ADODB.Command? I don't think that's the problem here, because I've tried running this same script with a non-parametrized query substituted for Month_Totals, and gotten the same error.

Comment: I don't know if this is applicable (I work in Access directly so never use ADODB), but I think there are no named parameters, so you need to work with them by order instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe The parameters are only for use when you are using a saved query in access. I would solve your problem by moving the parameters into the SQL statment.

Change

> ```
> "SELECT * FROM [Month_Totals]"
> ```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM [Month_Totals] WHERE Year = 2011 AND Month = 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is returning an error is that command type is set to `adCmdtable`, but the command does not reference a table, it references an SQL string, so:

```
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
```

Next, in order to return specific data, you need to include a WHERE clause, with field names in the correct order for the parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Month_Totals] Where [Year]=? AND [Month]=?"
```